# Failing to save Tensorflow weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using transfer learning to tackle a classification problem and its training process and the validation process work without any problem. I am using Tensorflow 1.13.2 and I am forced to use it since it is the only Tensorflow version which is supported by my hardware. The problem is when I use  `model.save('saved_model_1')` it does not save a .pb file as expected. What should I do to save the weight file properly.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph


def prepare_df(data_type):
    X = []
    y = []
    path = '../tf_files/hand_orientations/' + data_type + '/'

    for i in os.listdir(path):
        # Image
        X.append(i)
        # Label
        y.append(i.split('_')[0])

    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['filename'] = X
    df['label'] = y

    return df


df_train = prepare_df('training')
df_val = prepare_df('validation')
df_test = prepare_df('evaluation')

# Create the ImageDataGenerator object
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
)

# Generate batches and augment the images
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df_train,
    directory='../tf_files/hand_orientations/training/',
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='label',
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(224, 224),
)

val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df_val,
    directory='../tf_files/hand_orientations/validation/',
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='label',
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(224, 224),
)

# Initialize the Pretrained Model
base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet',
                       input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                       include_top=False)

print(base_model.summary())

# Set this parameter to make sure it's not being trained
base_model.trainable = False

# Set the input layer
input_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Set the feature extractor layer
x = base_model(input_, training=False)

# Set the pooling layer
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# Set the final layer with sigmoid activation function
output_ = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# Create the new model object
model = tf.keras.Model(input_, output_)

# Compile it
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print The Summary of The Model
model.summary()

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=20, validation_data=val_generator)

y_true = []
y_pred = []

for i in os.listdir('../tf_files/hand_orientations/evaluation'):
    img = Image.open('../tf_files/hand_orientations/evaluation/' + i)
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img = np.array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)

    y_true.append((i.split('_')[0]))
    y_pred.append('right' if model.predict(img) > 0.5 else 'left')

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
print()
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))

print(y_true)
print(y_pred)

model.save('saved_model_1')
```

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is `Tensorflow 1.x` model, Please save your model using:

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_save_path)    # model and path to save this model
```

To check saved_model format

```
ls {model_save_path}
```

Output:

```
assets/  saved_model.pb  variables/
```

To reload the model you can use below method:

```
tf.saved_model.load(model_save_path)
```

You can check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#creating_a_savedmodel_from_keras) reference for more details.